# Install packages using el-get

Tags: emacs, elisp, package

El-get is quite handy to install and manage packages from its own repository. If we install a customized packages(personal packages downloaded from github) from local directory in the ways below
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InstallingPackages  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath
is it possible to add them to the list of el-get and get management from it? Or Can we use el-get to install packages offline?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `file://` URLs with the `http` source type. e.g.:

```el
(defun my-local-repository-url-for (library)
  "Provide a URL for a library in ~/.emacs.d/local-repository/"
  (concat "file://" (expand-file-name user-emacs-directory)
          "local-repository/" library ".el"))

(setq el-get-sources
      `(;; [...]

        (:name ediff-binary-hexl
               :type http
               :url ,(my-local-repository-url-for "ediff-binary-hexl"))

        ;; [...]
        ))
```

In these cases you would tend *not* to have any other installation code for the library (e.g. manually manipulating `load-path`), as you should be able to specify everything you need in the el-get source config.